# Create directories with names similar to files

Tags: command-line, bash, directory, sort, mkdir

I have a lot of `.mp4` files, nearly 140, and I want to create directories with similar names to that of the files, but bash won't allow me to `mkdir`, saying `file exists`

How can I do it ?

Comment: please edit your question with more detail: what command are you using exactly? And give some examples of the names of the files

Comment: It's not very clear what you are asking, do you want to make a separate directory for each .mp4 file?

Comment: sorry , my english it's really bad .
i used this :
#!/bin/bash
data=`ls`
for folder in $data;do
           mkdir $folder
    fi
done

Comment: " i want to create directory with similar name with that files " you can't have a file and  directory in the same directory with the same name. You need to create the dirs somewhere else (and I would assume move the files over to that newly created directory).

Comment: your idea is great !

i try to do it . and say result :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to create folders with the EXACT same names as the files (including extension—for example .mp4) which is not allowed. You can use this script to make a directory with the same name as each file but without the extension:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *
do
mkdir "${file%.*}"
done
```

for example if you have files

```
nice.mp4  fun.mp4
```

after running the script you would have directories without extension & original files

```
nice  nice.mp4  fun  fun.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

Open your Ubuntu terminal window.

cd to your containing folder.

Write the following code in your terminal window:

for file in *

do

mkdir "${file%.*}"

done

Enter to execute.

You will have all the folders created for all the files in your directory, except for those already earlier created, which will be listed for you in the bash (terminal).